# Slow and weird draining process on Dataflow job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Dataflow job in streaming mode that is written in Apache Beam Python SDK and overall it works as expected, but, since from time to time we want to update the code, we need to deploy a new job and drain the old one. As soon as I press the "Drain" button, the job starts to act weird. It increases the number of workers to maximum allowed, which is expected, I know, but the CPU usage of those workers is crazy. Also, the "System Latency" metric is increasing. You can see in the screenshot below where I set it to drain, it's very visible.
[image]

You can see that the draining didn't finish for like 4 days, I had to cancel the job.
One thing I don't understand is why the "Throughput" of the DoFns is 0 all the time while the job is draining.
How can I change my job to make it more draining friendly?
You can find the code of the job in https://gist.github.com/PlugaruT/bd8ac4c007acbff5097cea33ccc1bbb1

Comment: What are yo using as a source? Also, are you setting any Timers? You could try https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-runner-v2 which handles drains better in some cases.

Comment: The pipeline is reading from pub/sub and inserting into BigQuery. No timers, the windowing fn is quite small, 60 seconds, also using the default triggers. Also, I already have the `--experiments=use_runner_v2` if this is what are you referring to.

Comment: have you seen this multiple times, or just the one time?

Comment: @Pablo We have 3 jobs that are running, but we often update this one, and we have seen this issue only when draining this job, not sure about the other. I can provide you 3 job ids that maybe can help you investigate. `2021-04-01_01_04_33-15566590661708392073`, `2021-05-04_11_31_56-9475672897419873800`, `2021-04-16_01_06_00-18014300968926826985`.